# How to make changes to a file in all of my previous commits?

Tags: git

I have a private repository. I was using MIT license. But now I want to change it to GPL3 before making it public. The problem is that if I change the license in a commit and push it, technically, you are allowed to use a previous commit according to MIT license (which I don't want).

Is there a way to change the license in all of the previous commits? I heard about doing it individually for each commit in git rebase but there needs to be a better way!

Comment: In what form is the license mentioned in your previous commits?

Comment: Providing a license does not transfer ownership. The code is still yours, and you can change its license it at any point. What you cannot do is retroactively revoke the terms under which someone else may have obtained and subsequently redistributed your code - the genie is out of the bottle, so to speak.

Comment: @tripleee, the code is not yet open source. No one has a copy of it. So, I am not revoking anyone's rights.

Comment: **This isn't a licensing or a legal question** - it asks how to change a specific file in all previous VCS commits, making it a VCS question and on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to change is a single file, do that and commit it.

Then you can use `git rebase -i` to rearrange commits. In particular, you can move the change to the license file to the beginning of history, as if it had always been there.

Answer (score 2):

You can not retroactively change a contract, as per principle of legal certainty. So the people who downloaded and use your software under MIT license can in no way be forced to cease usage of your software under the terms of MIT license up to the revision in which you changed to GPL

To prevent further clone your software under the MIT license, I would set up a new repo and use the current state as the initial commit, while deleting the old repo.

On the other hand - who would want to have an older version of the code, really?
Personally, I would simply change the license, add the new header to the files and every user of the current version would have to use it under GPL.

IANAL, but depending on the kind of software we are talking about, especially if it is a server of any kind, it could make sense to change to the [AGPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Affero_General_Public_License).

Comment: You're answering this like it's a legal question. OP has explicitly stated [it isn't open-source yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56089247/how-to-make-changes-to-my-license-in-all-of-my-previous-commits#56089247), meaning there are no contracts that can be changed. And the question is still about changing a file in all previous commits, not changing the license.

Comment: It's completely missing the point. It's a private repo; no one has a copy of the software yet.

Comment: @Zoe One has to understand the implications to understand the solution. I was not aware that the idea is to ignore that and spoon-feed just a solution.

Comment: @melpomene Nevertheless, wether it is public or not yet, with the current state, if published, the same principle applies.

Comment: true that @MarkusWMahlberg

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP already understands the implications, which is why they're trying to insert the license change in the past, before all other commits, so when it is published, people cannot get an older version under a different license.

Comment: And thats exactly Why I asked this question. Thanks for the relevant information.

Comment: Its fine. Don't fight for me. I got the solution

Comment: @Hemil I do fight. It has gotten thus far that not only some people dictate what is to be answered and why, but the structure as well.